# Pithy sweet potatoes - okay to eat?

Tags: food-safety, sweet-potatoes

This sweet potato is spongy and slightly holey inside. Is this safe to eat?

[image]

It's similar to this question, [Holes inside a sweet potato](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/83611/holes-inside-a-sweet-potato), but mine is only slight pithy/holey. The outside is normal. Some of the other slices look more normal.